# Round down to nearest usable fraction

Tags: excel

Im working in a welding shop and I want to cut my steel beams to the nearest usable fraction (1/16). It has to round down because I can always fill the space with weld. For example, I have a beam that is 140.47 on the drawing and when I use an excel function I get it to output 140 1/2"
The excel function is:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0"&IF(ABS(A1-ROUND(A1,0))>1/32," 0/"&CHOOSE(ROUND(MOD(A1,1)*16,0),16,8,16,4,16,8,16,2,16,8,16,4,16,8,16),""))&""""
```

How can I get it to round down and output 140 7/16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MROUND:

```
=MROUND(A1-(1/32),1/16)
```

Then format the output:

```
0 #/##
```

[image]

---

If you do not mind text as the final output:

```
=TEXT(MROUND(A1-(1/32),1/16),"0 #/##")
```